# Loading large json files (250mb+) with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

While I've looked here and in other sources, I cannot quite seem to find the issue with loading larger JSON (from a file) with XMLHttpRequest in javascript.  I generate this JSON file from a c# application and have never run into any issues with invalid json.  Smaller files (1mb - 100mb) load just fine.  I recently had a user tell me that they were not able to load their file (295.8mb) and were getting an `allocation size overflow` in Firefox.

I tested this with a small script which can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/fraguada/6k0k698g/

I'm running this locally and can load smaller files with no issues while this file in Firefox gives me the following error (line 8 in the jsfiddle)

```
allocation size overflow
callback(xobj.responseText);
```

In Chrome I get a different error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
(anonymous function) @ index.html:23 
xobj.onreadystatechange @ index.html:37
```

Here, index.html:23 refers to line 21 of the js fiddle (`JSON.parse(response)`) and line 37 refers to line 8 in the jsfiddle (`callback(xobj.responseText);`).

I've tried [oboe.js](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js) (very nice by the way), but after waiting a while (3 minutes), the loading stops (as shown by Chrome Dev tools), and I hit the `.fail` callback in oboe.

So, is it possible to load such files with XMLHttpRequest?  If not, which alternatives are there to do so?  My users are using my app locally and on the web.  While I had not planned for such large json files, I also didn't know there would be any limitation (other than available ram and bandwidth) to load such a file.

EDIT: Maybe it is better to ask:
- What limits the amount of data that can be loaded by XMLHttpRequest?  Is it the browser heap?  Is it the amount of RAM on the client?  Is it the XMLHttpRequest object?

Comment: i find anything over 10mb starts to slowdown more than scale alone would suggest. 250MB is likely a no-go.

Comment: As I mentioned, loading files that are 1mb-100mb works fine.  I have a progress this bar informing the user of what is going on.  It is only with this 295mb file that things are going wrong.

Comment: I've been able to load a 205mb file just fine...

Comment: Why do you want to load 250 MB worth of JSON into the browser? This does not sound like a good plan to me.

Comment: My users might have large files.  I am using json as a format for a file coming from another application (in another format).  My application is a viewer for these files.

Comment: Still not a good idea, at all. A GMail Inbox inbox might be several gigabytes in size, and the GMail web app is a viewer for that thing. Still it does not download *everything* before it displays something.

Comment: That is a fair comment.  I am not saying it is a good idea, what I am asking is where the limit comes from?  What imposes this limit which triggers these allocation size overflow errors?  I am already working on a progressive loading of the json data and optimizing the data within the file.  The data itself is a 3d scene, so it is different than having email topics displayed.  A user typically will want to see the entire scene.

Comment: i see several mentions over the web that say "_by default v8 has a memory limit of 512MB on 32-bit systems, and 1.4GB on 64-bit systems_". since unicode use 2 bytes per char, a 250mb string would seem to present a limit to 32bit systems even without the RAM used by the parsed Object.

Comment: For what it's worth, Oboe.js uses an XMLHttpRequest under the hood, so it's possible the limitations do come from there :)

Comment: @JuanCaicedo, yes,  I'm aware oboe.js uses XMLHttpRequest under the hood.  I'm really liking the things I can do with oboe.js.  Thanks for your contribution!  The closest I've come to answering this is what dandavis wrote about the v8 constraints,  but my tests are not yet conclusive.