# Load large <script type="application/json" with bokeh and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, bokeh

I am currently having a size issue when I create a graph using bokeh. 
I write my python/bokeh script and export the result to an html file. It works fine.

However, I have so much data that the final html file is around 30Mb.
It loads on the web browser but it takes a long time (1min).
That is not very practical if I was to deploy it on the web.

Opening the html file, I see that the 30Mb of data are embedded in:

```
<script type="application/json" id="myID">
```

and this is later called with:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var fn = function() {
          Bokeh.safely(function() {
            (function(root) {
              function embed_document(root) {

              var docs_json = document.getElementById('myID').textContent;
```

I was wondering if it was possible to either create an external json and load it more efficiently (compress? using XMLHttpRequest()? using Ajax? buffering?)

So far I have found posts like:
[Loading large json files (250mb+) with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043725/loading-large-json-files-250mb-with-xmlhttprequest), and javascript library such as 'oboejs' (http://oboejs.com/)
but I was not unable to achieve something.

Since I do not have any experience with javascript maybe I am missing something obvious.

Thank you in very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you need the whole "30MB" data in the webpage or is paging the result also an option?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I need the "30MB" in the webpage because it is a dynamic graph that requires all the data. I am now looking at stream-json as an option but no success yet.